# RequiredfieldValidator not working for all controls on button click if onblur event is set for textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I have a form in which I have 5 asp textboxes and have taken 5 requiredfieldvalidator for each. For each textbox have set event `onblur="ValidatorOnChange(event);"` to make `requiredfiedvalidator` to validate control on lost focus of each.

I have also set jquery document.ready() event to focus on first text box.

Having a `command  button` for which i have set `casusesvalidation` property true and each `textbox`, `validator` and `command button` have same `validation group`.

Now what problem am I facing is, on `click` event of command `button`, the validation error message is displaying for first text box only. It should be displayed for each textbox on click event of button while for single textbox on lost focus of that specific textbox.

I am facing this in chrome and safari only. Not in IE as well as Firefox.

Any solution??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **onchange**-Event in place of your **onblur** event

Comment: :) there is alot difference between onchange and onblur, onchange will only be fired if I make any change in textbox values. Suppose I have focus on my textbox1 and I have set onchange event to validate textbox for requiredfiledvalidator then it will not validate if I simply move to textbox2 using Tab key press. :)